# A sequence of simple measurable nonnegative functions converge to a measurable function.

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is a measurable nonnegative function, we know there are simple measurable nonnegative functions that converges to it. Why is the converse true? That is, if have a a sequence of increasing simple measurable nonnegative functions that converges to a function $f$, how do we know this $f$ is not a simple function?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be simple?

Comment: @DanielFischer well it might simple as well, no?

Comment: Yes, it may be simple or not. What we know from the hypotheses is that it's nonnegative and measurable.